# Knowing the number of negative eigenvalues of a $ A $ operator, is it possible to know of the $ -A $?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H=(H, (\cdot, \cdot)_H)$ be a Hilbert space and $A: D(A) \subset H \longrightarrow H$ be a linear, densely defined and self-adjoint operator. Suppose that the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of $A$ is formed by a sequence of real numbers $(\lambda_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$
\lambda_0 < \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2< \cdots < \lambda_{2n-1}\leq \lambda_{2n} \cdots.
$$

**Question.** If the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$, denoted by $\text{n}(A)$, is equal $k \in \mathbb{N}$, that is, $\text{n}(A)=k$, what I can conclude about $\text{n}(-A)$?

I know that if $-\lambda^2<0$ is a negative eigenvalue of $A$, with $v \in D(A)$ eigenvector associated, then
$$
A(v)=-\lambda^2v \quad \Rightarrow \quad -A(v)=\lambda^2v 
$$
and hence $\lambda^2>0$ is a positive eigenvalue of the operator $-A$. What can I conclude from that? Can I conclude that $\text{n}(-A)>k$?

Comment: You can construct operators with arbitrary numbers of positive and negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @KeithMcClary And how does that help answer my question?

Comment: As I understand you,  $n(-A)$ is the number of positive eigenvalues of $A$.